# Bluetooth pin request dialog appears even for paired device (Nexus 5)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm developing a simple app to connect 2 devices via bluetooth and faced the next problem: on my Nexus 5 there are always a prompt to enter pin code, even if the second device is paired(it is in paired devices list and it's bond state == BOND_BONDED). On Samsung Galaxy S3 there are no such a problem, prompt only appears for the connection attempt. 
Could you please advise if there any way to hide pin request dialog for the second connection attempt or somehow emulate pin entering?

I tried several solutions, proposed on SO, but none of them worked:

```
1. device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device, true); 

2. device.setPairingConfirmation(false)

3. Method mm = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
   mm.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

4. device.createBond()

5. device.setPin(pin)
```